# Platformer jitter from two boxcollider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a platform for my player to walk on, which is a bunch of squares with BoxColliders attached, but when the players boxcollider runs on top of the platform, it creates a subtle jitter. I have tried adding a CircleCollider to the player but this does not fix the problem. Any ideas?

```
public class PController : MonoBehaviour {
private Rigidbody2D rgdby;
public float moveS;

void Start () {
rgdby = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();}

void Update (){
if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")>0f){
rgdby.velocity = new Vector3 (moveS, rgdby.velocity.y,0f);
    }
else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")<0f){
rgdby.velocity = new Vector3(-moveS, rgdby.velocity.x,0f);}         
else{
rgdby.velocity = new Vector3(0f,rgdby.velocity.y,0f);}}
}
```

The above is attached to the character

Comment: Provide [mcve] ...

Comment: hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to add some sample code.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am not sure if this is a code issue. I just tried creating one large boxcollider, rather than 5small ones and this fixes the jitter. But, surely doing that isnt good practise? Surely when I add a 1x1 prefab and put another next to it, that should work?

Comment: You explain that the players movement triggers the jittering. You need to show us how you move the player and preferably also which components are attached to the player and the boxes. Code should be displayed as code (which you can format it to if you edit your question) and inspector views can be displayed as screenshots.

Comment: Hi Doh09, I never thought this could be a code issue I have attached the code. This is attached to the character who also has a rigidbody. and the platform just has boxcolliders.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention 2 possible fixes.

1. Update your velocity of the rigidbody inside a Fixed Update.
2. And try multiplying your velocity with Time.fixedDeltaTime or Time.deltaTime.